# Simplest way to assign numeric ranges to values in php?

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, switch-statement

I'm trying to create a more simple version of if/else php statements because there are very many of them, so I want to make the code shorter and simpler.

I thought since each outputted value will equal a number going up from 0, then maybe I can do an array, but I'm also open to other solutions.

In human language, I want the value to be one of these numbers between 0 and 4 if it is within different parts of a range of numbers:

```
//  4 = 10,000+
//  3 = 1000-9,999
//  2 = 500-999
//  1 = 100-499
//  0 = <100
```

e.g. if `$aa` is `547`, then `$zz` should equal the numeric value of `2`, because it falls within 500-1000.

Now using if/else it's possible, and that works, but I want to make it shorter. Here it is in if/else statements:

```
if ( $aa >= 10000 ) {
    $zz = 4;
} else if ( $aa >= 1000 && $aa < 10000 ) {
    $zz = 3;
} else if ( $aa >= 500 && $aa < 1000 ) {
    $zz = 2;
} else if ( $aa >= 100 && $aa < 500 ) {
    $zz = 1;
} else {
    $zz = 0;
}
```

Now I tried making an array but having trouble figuring out how to do this. Here's what I started with:

```
$b4 = $aa >= 10000;
$b3 = $aa >= 1000 && $aa < 10000;
$b2 = $aa >= 500 && $aa < 1000;
$b1 = $aa >= 100 && $aa < 500;
$b0 = $aa < 100;

$b_val = array( $b0, $b1, $b2, $b3, $b4 );
```

This is terribly wrong I know. It's not going to work like that, but maybe there's a way to make it work.

I thought of using `switch`, but it seems switch isn't designed for this, even though it can be done, and it isn't any shorter. I thought of using ternary, but that doesn't seem shorter either, unless you know how.

How to get a short, crisp, clean code to shorten the if/else statement on ranges of numbers?

Comment: Your ranges are overlapping (at least in the _"human language"_ description) so the results will be indeterminant

Comment: Yeah I literally just figured that out and came back to edit the post. Nice catch! It's supposed to be `&&` not `||`. As for the human readable, you know what I meant but I edited that too.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up. I just wanted to make sure before answering

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested ternary working smallest to largest

```php
$zz = $aa < 100 ? 0 : ($aa < 500 ? 1 : ($aa < 1000 ? 2 : ($aa < 10000 ? 3 : 4)));
```

Demo ~ https://3v4l.org/MnqQv

I'd argue it's not as readable and therefore not as good as a plain old `if..elseif..else` or a function that returns at the appropriate logic branch.

```php
function getRangeIndex($aa) {
    if ($aa < 100) return 0;
    if ($aa < 500) return 1;
    if ($aa < 1000) return 2;
    if ($aa < 10000) return 3;
    return 4;
}
```

Comment: ok but is there a cleaner and more efficient way than if/else?

Comment: @sdsdc1 did you not see the nested ternary option?